# Getting a 404 error for index page

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.2

I keep getting this error when trying to go the index page in kohana

> Kohana_HTTP_Exception[ 404 ]:The requested URL localwebsite/admin was not found onthis server.

SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Request\Client\Internal.php [ 79 ]:

```
   if ( ! class_exists($prefix.$controller))
     {
      throw HTTP_Exception::factory(404,'The requested URL :uri was not found on this server.',
      array(':uri' => $request->uri()))->request($request);
     }
     // Load the controller using reflection
     $class = new ReflectionClass($prefix.$controller);
```

SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Request\Client.php[114]:

```
    Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(args)
```

SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Request.php [ 990 ]:

```
Kohana_Request_Client->execute(arguments)
```

DOCROOT\index.php [ 118 ]:

```
Kohana_Request->execute()
```

Comment: What routes have you set up? Is the `base_url` set correct?

Comment: You can add `var_dump($prefix.$controller)` right after `if ( ! class_exists($prefix.$controller))` clause to see which controller file does Kohana wants.

Answer (score -1):

Kohana is a very robust framework and the number one rule is to not go through the system or modules folders!

You shouldn't ever be blaming issues like this on the framework but instead check your routes/start a new project to find the problems that way.

Stay in the application folder because as soon as you start messing with /system and /modules you cannot upgrade kohana :(